# thread-safe stopwatch API

Tags: java, thread-safety, stopwatch

I am wondering how to write a thread-safe stopwatch. Below is a simple stopwatch implementation, and it provide basic operations of a stopwatch, but it is not thread-safe.

Now, all that I can think about is to add synchronize to each methods (start(), lap(), stop(), reset()). Is there exist some other way to achieve thread-safety on the stopwatch?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Stopwatch {
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    private boolean isRunning;

    // lapTimes is able to record all the lap time.
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Long> lapTimes;

    Stopwatch() {
        isRunning = false;
        lapTimes = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Long>();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            isRunning = true;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("cannot start when running!");
        }
    }

    public void lap() {
        if (isRunning) {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lapTimes.add(endTime - startTime);
            startTime = endTime;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("cannot lap when not running!!");
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (isRunning) {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lapTimes.add(endTime - startTime);
            isRunning = false;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("cannot stop when not running!");
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        isRunning = false;
        lapTimes.clear();
    }

    public List<Long> getLapTime() {
        return lapTimes;
    }
```

}

What I want to do is to share one stopwatch object by multiple threads.

Suppose we have two threads: thread A and thread B. Thread A start the stopwatch, and several seconds late, it called stop. While it just finished if statement(the first line in stop method), thread B was invoked, and it also called stop method. Later, thread A continued to execute stop method without any exceptions.

This is not what I want, since a thread-safe stopwatch could not be stopped twice, and I just want to know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Seeing as most of those methods need access to most of the object's fields, you might as well make them synchronised. You could gain a performance benefit if the various methods needed access to different "resources" and it would be feasible to implement finer-grained locks, but that's not the case here.

Comment: I don't think it's sensible to try to make this class thread safe. For example, what should happen if one thread calls `start` and one calls `stop`? If you made it thread safe, the result would be essentially random, which wouldn't be useful anyway. Whatever code is going to call into this code has to synchronize *itself* or it will get nonsense results no matter what this class does -- so why pay the overhead for synchronization that won't actually solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want it to be thread safe because... (a) multiple threads could be starting the stopwatch and doings laps, or (b) one thread might start the stopwatch while another thread could complete a lap with that same stopwatch?

Comment: I think I want to achieve the second one, while the first one seems that each thread has its own stopwatch, and thus will not share the one object.